# PHP's HTML Tidy removes Facebook's FBML

Tags: php, facebook, fbml, tidy

I know FBML is deprecated though I still have a question about it (maintaining some legacy code).

I'm using FBML in a template which gets parsed by PHP's Tidy, unfortunately TIDY strips the FBML code. Do you know of a workaround to use Tidy + FBML?

Example FMBL Code:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/vanity.url"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Have you tried defining it as XHTML & setting the `xmlns:fb` namespace? Because that would be about the _only_ way to get the (X)HTML valid. Tidy is right :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but yes, the beginning of the page's code is:

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de" xml:lang="de-DE" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 

And the FB-Javascript Line to initialize FBML is there too:

    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>

Comment: Hm, (1) drop those `;`'s, (2) maybe it needs `input-xml=true` in the config, seems to work here, but I don't know whether it misses something else in that case (technically, the content is XHTML+XML afaik).

Comment: (1) The ;'s are not in the code, seems stackoverflow replaces line break with them.

Comment: (2) You're my hero, input-xml=true does the trick! Many Thanks.

Comment: Would be great if you'd repost the comment as an answer so I can mark the question as answered an give you credit.

Comment: Aight, done. (And didn't know that about those `;`'s, weird choice for SO where syntax matters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides neeeding to be XHTML & setting the `xmlns:fb` namespace (`<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="facebook.com/2008/fbml">`), it needs `input-xml`=`true` in the config, seems to work here (technically, the content is XHTML+XML afaik, not 'pure' (x)html).